# voting arrows on comments have "hand-drawn" look

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

I'm very happy with the design of the site. Which is why this tiny little thing is bugging me a bit.

The up-vote triangle for comments have a hand-drawn look, slightly reminiscent of the beta design. Everything else in the site has such clean, crisp lines, I don't understand the logic of having these as the icons. I understand that we want to distinguish between the main voting icons and those for comments, and I like triangles....but why not use clean crisp ones? If we want something tex-related, we could use \shortuparrow or \Uparrow...

What do other people think?

Comment: now I have some time to look at everything in practice since the new design has launched, I agree with you. I'll tweak comment arrows. But it may be sometimes next week when I do. The comment vote arrows have the same style as the old up/down vote arrows for questions I originally designed.

Comment: @jin: that sounds great.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the image for the comment voting arrow. It will be in the next deployment tomorrow. Since it's part of the sprites.png, it may be cached by your browser. Make sure to hard refresh.

Comment: I noticed the new normal and mouse-over versions have a tiny vertical displacement of a pixel or two. Also their size is not the same -- the mouse-over version is slightly bigger (is that [status-by-design]?)

Comment: I like it better, and second the question by Martin.

Comment: @Martin they're the same size, you can see from img/sprites.png. I think it's the position glitch that makes them seem different. I'll fix the bug soon.

Comment: the fix for the hover position glitch will be in the next deployment.